# ClickOnce and ODP.NET 12c managed dll

Tags: clickonce, odp.net

Looking at the comments/info on the new Managed dll for ODP.NET in 12c ... it appears that using it in a ClickOnce deployment is as "simple and beautiful" as

1) Referencing the managed dll instead of unmanaged
2) Set CopyLocal=true
3) Make sure the app doesn't depend on things that would be part of a pre-installed Oracle client, e.g. tnsnames.ora

Is this correct? (Aka : Has Santa come early this year?)

Answer (score 1):

We have been able to use the CopyLocal feature to include the managed odp.net dll with our application. When this application was then installed on a machine that had only Win 7 and NO Oracle software installed at all, it was able to connect to an Oracle database on a server and run properly.

The opd.net dll is managed, MSIL and does not need to be in the GAC on the installed machine.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the assembly can be used running locally, or needs to be installed in the GAC. If you can just include it in the deployment and it will work, then you should add it to the project.

If the assembly is referenced in the code, set the build action to 'none' and 'copy to output directory' to false. Then when you add the reference, point it at the assembly included in the project, and set 'copy local' to true.

If the assembly is not referenced in the code, set the build action to 'copy always' and the type to 'content'.

Answer (score 0):

YES!!!! With Oracle.ManagedDataAccess we were able to deploy entire oracle client through ClickOnce, so you don't need a separate client install. This is what was different for me from regular unmanaged ODP.NET:

1). Put all the connection information directly in your connection string, as opposed to referencing TNSNames.ora. eg.

```
  string sEZconnect = string.Format("Data Source={0}:{1}/{2};User ID={3};Password={4};"
                                                          , databaseServerName //the server the database resides on
                                                          , "1521"             //TNSlistener port (1521 is default)
                                                          , instanceName       // the name of the database instance on the server
                                                          , userName
                                                          , password);
        OracleConnection _connection = new OracleConnection(sEZconnect);
```

2). In addition to refrencing Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, I also needed to refrence Oracle.ManagedDataAcesssDTC, which I could only add by browsing.  I show the 64 bit version below, the 32 bit version of Oracle.ManagedDataAcesssDTC.dll is in the same \managed directory.

That is all that was necessary to successfully deploy the Oracle client in my ClickOnce app.  Nothing added in App.config, just changed the connection string and made sure the two .dll's above were set to CopyLocal=true.

The download was the "ODP.NET, Managed Driver" from Oracle at:`http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html`

[image]